# Static public and private access in example

Tags: java, oop

The question is:

Write the definition of a class `Counter` containing:

- An instance variable named counter
  of type  `int` .
- An instance variable  named   `limit` of type  `int`  .
- A static  `int` variable  named   `nCounters` which is initialized  to  0 .
- A constructor  taking two `int` parameters  that assigns  the first one to  `counter` and 
  the second one to  `limit` . It also adds one to the static variable   `nCounters` .
- A method  named  `increment`  . It does not take parameters  or return a value ; if the
  instance variable   `counter` is less than   `limit` , increment  just adds one to the 
  instance variable   `counter` .
- A method  named   `decrement` that also doesn't take parameters  or return a value ; if
  `counter` is greater than  zero, it just subtracts one from the  `counter` .
- A method  named   `getValue` that returns the value  of the instance variable   `counter` .
- A static  method  named   `getNCounters` that returns the value  of the static variable 
  `nCounters` .

**My Dilemma**

The code works fine but I want to know the following:

**Why is the first static private and the second one public?**

My code:

```
public class Counter 
{
    private int counter;
    private int limit;
    private static int nCounters = 0;
    public Counter (int x, int y)
    {
        counter = x;
        limit   = y;
        nCounters++;
    }
    public void increment () 
    {
        if( counter < limit)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    public void decrement () 
    {
        if(counter > 0)
        {
            counter--;
        }
    }
    public int getValue ()
    {
        return counter;
    }
    public static int getNCounters ()
    {
        return nCounters;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you edit your question to format it so that it's readable (that includes the code!).

Comment: I hope that helps - the site is wont allow me to post it as i have it in turings craft. Thank you for your help.

Comment: After looking at your previous questions I've retagged this as *java*, please correct it yourself if I was wrong. You should always specify the programming language in question tags—Stack Overflow is by no means a Java-only forum.

Comment: A good example of everyone overwriting one another's edits causing some chaos. But hopefully it's stabilized now.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - I tried to tag it as java but the website said i did not have enough reputation. What is a better option then?

Comment: @user2168239 - Are you sure you didn't try to [create a new tag](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) rather than using the existing one?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
Hmmm. Perhaps. but all i did was type java as a tag.
Also, i cant seem to ask question again - as if my account has been blocked. I just joined a few hours ago.Do you know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nCounters` is a variable that you use to count the numbers of times the Class constructor has been called. It's `static` because is not a instance variable but a class variable (its value is shared by all the instances of that class).

`nCounter` is privated for encapsulate it. It can only be accessed outside the class by a read only method named `getNCounters`. Otherwise, I could access the value of `nCounter` and change it directly causing the value of classes created not reliable anymore.

You can read more about [encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) and [static methods and variables](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html) to understanding better your code.

Comment: That's great. makes sense now.

Comment: How do you mean @Averroes?

Comment: Use the arrows to upvote the useful answers and the check to accept the valid answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The first static variable `nCounters` is private, because you want to control it in your class - you do not want any code outside of `Counter` to modify it. But you want to make it possible to read its value outside of `Counter`, thus the `getNCounters()` method is public.